# can anyone explain the luhn algorithm given in below program?

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3zPa.png)

can anyone explain the program.
this program is given by our teacher he said it is about luhn algorithm i found out what is it but i am unable to understand to the program.

Comment: WIth a picture of text you will not make people feel especially helpful.

Comment: An image may say more than a thousand words, but actual code, as text, says more than a thousand images.

Comment: I recommend writing an explanation of the luhn algorithm as you understand it. You will be surprised how much that helps to understand the code you are looking at.

Comment: Not only will explaining the algorithm (and its application here) to the best of your understanding help *you*, it will also help *us* figure out which parts you have right and just where you need help.  And *please* post the code as text, not picture.

Comment: Unconditionally returning from loop body doesn't look right...

Answer (score 0):

After reading the Wikipedia article about the Luhn algorithm, the application int the program is clear.

Every credit card number has a "check digit" as its last digit.  That digit makes it so that when the Luhn algorithm is applied, the result is an even multiple of 10.  If someone mistypes the card number, chances are good that it will not add up to a multiple of 10, catching the error before bothering to check the credit card with the CC company.

That's what the program does: it checks that the credit card number "looks" legitimate.  Try it on your own CC, and then try it on the same CC number but with a mistake.

The Luhn function you posted returns a true value if the result is evenly divisible by 10.